# Data Extraction using Beautiful Soup : Data Visible on Website But No Text or Value present in HTML Tags

Tags: jquery, python, selenium, beautifulsoup, data-extraction

I am trying to extract data from a website
[image]

with HTML 
[image]

I am unable to extract text from HTML.I am using Python,Selenium and Beautiful SOUP to extract data.I checked from jquery using CSS Selector.
[image]

How to select value using python as it is working in jquery

Comment: Did you try `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[placeholder="Type your question here"]').get_attribute('value')`?

Comment: thanks @Andersson :)

Comment: Please read why a [**`screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea`**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based HTML and code trials.

Answer (score 0):

[`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) supports CSS selectors so just take your selector from jQuery and use it with [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)

[CSS selectors in **BS4**:](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)

```
soup.select("title")
# [<title>The Dormouse's story</title>]

soup.select("p:nth-of-type(3)")
# [<p class="story">...</p>]
```

Answer (score 0):

From the `HTML` you have provided it is pretty clear that the following outermost `<input>` tag have no text set by `default` but have a `placeholder` as **`Type your question here`**.

So in this particular state of the **`HTML DOM`** if you try to extract the `text` from this particular `<input>` tag you won't be getting intended results. So what you experianced is justified.

In the next step you have typed in the text **`My Name is khan`** in the `Search Box` which is again an `<input>` tag but seems to me a different on as per the **`cssSelector`** which you have used through the `Developers Console` module.

The probable reason why you were able to pull out the text through the above mentioned **`cssSelector`** is because of the presence of **`JavaScript`**/**`jQuery`** which populates the **`HTML DOM`** either through [**`onkeyup Event`**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) or through [**`onfocusout Event`**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/onfocusout/info).

Hence by the time you query through the `Developers Console` the `value` attribute is populated with the search text **`My Name is khan`** and you are able to retrieve the text.